# Get API data and displaying it in a GUI window

Tags: python, api

I am new to python and programming in general. 
I have 2 questions: 
1. I am trying to build a GUI that askes the user for input details to connect directly to a device via IP and subscribe to its API. I have managed to write working console code, but want to make it more user friendly in a GUI.
2. The output I get needs to be parsed correctly and displayed in the bottom frame of my input window.

**Here is what I have so far...**

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import json
from websocket import create_connection

IP=input('Enter camera IP address:    ')
Type=input('Data or Event ? (Case sensitive):   ')
Data ={
  "messageType":"Subscription",
  "subscription":{
  "type":"Data",
"action":"Subscribe"
  }
}
Event={
  "messageType":"Subscription",
  "subscription":{
    "type":"Event",
    "action":"Subscribe"
  }
}
main_api = 'ws://'
API= '/api/subscriptions'
ws = create_connection(main_api + IP + API)
ws.connect(main_api + IP + API)
print ('Connected !')
if Type =='Data':
  ws.send(json.dumps(Data))
if Type =='Event':
  ws.send(json.dumps(Event))

while True:

    result = ws.recv()    
    jsondata = json.loads(result)
    print ("Web Socket data received : \n'%s'" % result)
    print('')

    ws.close()
```

**Result:**

Enter camera IP address:    192.168.16.119
Data or Event ? (Case sensitive):   Data
Connected !
Web Socket data received : 
'{'messageType': 'Subscription', 'subscription': {'returnValue': 'OK', 'type': 'Data'}}'

Web Socket data received : 
'{'dataNumber': '15751', 'intervalTime': '10', 'messageType': 'Data', 'time': '2018-09-12T10:02:00.001+01:00', 'type': 'PresenceData', 'zone': [{'numVeh': '0', 'zoneId': '1', 'zoneOccupancy': '0'}, {'numVeh': '0', 'zoneId': '2', 'zoneOccupancy': '0'}]}'

Web Socket data received : 
'{'dataNumber': '15752', 'intervalTime': '10', 'messageType': 'Data', 'time': '2018-09-12T10:02:10.030+01:00', 'type': 'PresenceData', 'zone': [{'numVeh': '1', 'zoneId': '1', 'zoneOccupancy': '6'}, {'numVeh': '0', 'zoneId': '2', 'zoneOccupancy': '0'}]}'

Web Socket data received : 
'{'dataNumber': '15753', 'intervalTime': '10', 'messageType': 'Data', 'time': '2018-09-12T10:02:20.059+01:00', 'type': 'PresenceData', 'zone': [{'numVeh': '0', 'zoneId': '1', 'zoneOccupancy': '0'}, {'numVeh': '0', 'zoneId': '2', 'zoneOccupancy': '0'}]}'

**2. Here is the code im using for the GUI:**

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import json
import sys
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from websocket import create_connection
from tkinter.constants import *

def ipinput ():
    iptext = ipent.get()
    iplabel2 = Label (ipGui, text=iptext).pack()
    return

def connect ():
ws = create_connection('ws://'+ ipinput + API)
ws.connect('ws://' + ipinput + API)
return

def result ():
     result = ws.recv()    
     jsondata = json.loads(result)
     print ("Web Socket data received : \n'%s'" % jsondata)
     print('')
     return

ipGui = Tk()
ipGui.geometry('450x450+500+300')
ipGui.title('Flir API Interface')

ipent = StringVar()
Apient = StringVar()

iplabel = Label (ipGui, text='Enter IP Address:').pack()
mEntry = Entry(ipGui, textvariable=ipent).pack()
Apilabel = Label (ipGui, text='Data or Event ?  CaSe Sensitive!!!').pack()
ApiEntry = Entry(ipGui, textvariable=Apient).pack()

connectbutton = Button(ipGui, text ='Connect',command = connect).pack()
Connectlabel = Label (ipGui, text='Connection output:').pack()
resultbutton = Button(ipGui, text ='Result',command = result).pack()
Connectlabel = Label (ipGui, text='Result output:').pack()
xbutton = Button(ipGui, text ="Exit",command = ipGui.destroy).pack()

mainloop()


Type=Apient

def connect ():
     main_api = 'ws://'
     API= '/api/subscriptions'
     ws = create_connection(main_api + ipent + API)
     ws.connect(main_api + ipent + API)

if Type =='Data':
         ws.send(json.dumps(Data))
if Type =='Event':
         ws.send(json.dumps(Event))

Data ={
  "messageType":"Subscription",
  "subscription":{
    "type":"Data",
    "action":"Subscribe"
  }
}
Event={
  "messageType":"Subscription",
  "subscription":{
    "type":"Event",
    "action":"Subscribe"
  }
}

while True:

    result = ws.recv()    
    jsondata = json.loads(result)
    print ("Web Socket data received : \n'%s'" % jsondata)
    print('')

ws.close()
```

[image]

Thank you for reading this long post. Hope the info helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "parsed correctly"? And what is your problem with the GUI?

Comment: Hi I want the info to be displayed in a format like this:

DataNumber = 1560
Time = 2018-09-12 - 10:02
          Zone id  1 
                          NumVeh  = 2 
                          ZoneOccupancy = 60%
           Zone id  2 
                          NumVeh  = 6 
                          ZoneOccupancy = 40%

As far as the GUI...I would like to display the above data on the lower frame of the window in its own box. This data is pushed from the device in real time so must be updated as it is received